# Custom endpoint in AWS powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, eucalyptus, aws-powershell

I am trying to use AWS Powershell with Eucalyptus.

I can do this with AWS CLI with parameter --endpoint-url.

Is it possible to set endpoint url in AWS powershell?
Can I create custom region with my own endpoint URL in AWS Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*--UPDATE--*

The newer versions of the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell (I'm running 3.1.66.0 according to Get-AWSPowerShellVersion), has an optional -EndpointUrl parameter for the relevant commands.

Example:

```
Get-EC2Instance -EndpointUrl https://somehostnamehere
```

Additionally, the aforementioned  [bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/240) has been fixed.

Good stuff!

---

--*ORIGINAL ANSWER--*

**TL;TR**

- Download the default endpoint config file from here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/endpoints.json
- Customize it. Example:

  ```
  {
      "version": 2,
      "endpoints": {
          "*/*": {
              "endpoint": "your_endpoint_here"
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- After importing the AWSPowerShell module, tell the SDK to use your customized endpoint config. Example:

  ```
  [Amazon.AWSConfigs]::EndpointDefinition = "path to your customized Amazon.endpoints.json here"
  ```

*Note: there is a [bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/240) in the underlying SDK that causes endpoints that have a path component from being signed correctly. The bug affects this solution and the solution @HyperAnthony proposed.*

**Additional Info**

Reading through the .NET SDK docs, I stumbled across a section that revealed that one can global set the region rules given a file: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/V2/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-config-other.html#config-setting-awsendpointdefinition

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anywhere where the format of such a file is documented.

I then splunked through the AWSSDK.Core.dll [code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/tree/master/sdk/src/Core) and found where the SDK loads the file (see LoadEndpointDefinitions() method at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/RegionEndpoint.cs).

Reading through the code, if a file isn't explicitly specified on AWSConfigs.EndpointDefinition, it ultimately loads the file from an embedded resource (i.e. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/endpoints.json)

Comment: @stkxchng Probably a little late, but I stumbled across this solution when wrestling with the same problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: I use EndpointUrl property, but AWS adds bucket name to URL (it forces virtual host mode).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it is. This list of [common parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/pstoolsref-commonparams.html) (that can be used with all AWS PowerShell cmdlets) does not include a Service URL, it seems instead to opt for a simple string `Region` to set the Service URL based on a set of known regions.

This [AWS .NET Development forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=313710) suggests that you can set the Service URL on a .NET SDK config object, if you're interested in a possible alternative in PowerShell. Here's an example usage from that thread:

```
$config=New-Object Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Config
$config.ServiceURL = "https://ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
$client=[Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonEC2Client($accessKeyID,$secretKeyID,$config)
```

It looks like you can use it with most config objects when setting up a client. Here's some examples that have the ServiceURL property. I would imagine that this is on most all AWS config objects:

- [AmazonEC2Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TEC2_EC2Config_NET4_5.html)
- [AmazonS3Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TS3_S3Config_NET4_5.html)
- [AmazonRDSConfig](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TRDS_RDSConfig_NET4_5.html)

Older versions of the documentation (for v1) noted that this property will be ignored if the `RegionEndpoint` is set. I'm not sure if this is still the case with v2.

Comment: Thank you, using .NET SDK from within powershell is acceptable for me